# Function Pointer and GCC warning

Tags: c, gcc

I'm currently learning how to write shellcode and get a GCC warning "assignment of incompatible pointer type". Why?

Greetings,
LM

```
char shellcode[] = 
  "\x31\xc0"
  "\xb0\x01"
  "\x31\xdb"
  "\xcd\x80";


int main() {
  void (*func)() = shellcode;

  func();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to cast the `char*` to the right type. Note that function pointers aren't guaranteed to be compatible with data pointers on all CPU architectures... but if you're writing shellcode I imagine you know your target ("victim"?) architecture well anyway!

Comment: Slight aside: Note that on a modern OS that's worth its salt, your `char` array will not be mapped into memory as "executable".  You may have to look into `mprotect` (on Unixy systems) or `VirtualAlloc` (on Windows).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll write my suggestion as an answer and whore for some reputation :-)

You need to explicitly cast the data pointer into a function pointer. With a typedef for the appropriate function pointer, you can do so without making the code too hard to read:

```
char shellcode[] = 
    "\x31\xc0"
    "\xb0\x01"
    "\x31\xdb"
    "\xcd\x80";

typedef void (*SHELLCODE)(void);

int main() {
    SHELLCODE func = (SHELLCODE) shellcode;
    func();

    /* ...and this will work as well, which some might find more readable: */
    ((SHELLCODE) shellcode)();

    return 0;
}
```

This compiles cleanly with clang 1.1, but GCC 4.4.3 will still give you a warning about the pointer conversion -- although now it is a more precise warning:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -ansi -pedantic shellcode.c 
shellcode.c: In function ‘main’:
shellcode.c:10: warning: ISO C forbids conversion of object pointer to function pointer type
shellcode.c:14: warning: ISO C forbids conversion of object pointer to function pointer type
```

Skipping the "-pedantic" flag will make it compile cleanly with GCC too, but who ever does that seriously?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, I think I found a solution, but I don't know if I it could be written better:

```
long (*func)() = (long (*)())shellcode;
```

No warnings with this code

Comment: It could be improved with a typedef, otherwise it was exactly was I was about to answer :-)

Comment: Don't do that, really. Look into your compiler manual and learn how to include assembler code into a function, I guess all mondern compilers should have such an extension. Or if your compiler doesn't have that, just write your code as assembler and link to the object that you define.

Answer (score 1):

There is no implicit conversion of object pointers to function pointers.  You'll need an explicit cast `(void(*)())` (and even that isn't guaranteed to work, or compile).

Answer (score 0):

Because `char[]` is incompatible with `void(*)()`!! What on earth would that even mean?

Comment: Well, they're both pointers. An explicit cast will do the trick. What would it mean? It would mean that the `char[]` contains something that will be run as a function.

Comment: You might get away with this with a given compiler, but it is undefined behavior and generally frowned upon.

Comment: "What on earth would that even mean?" -- I believe the OP is trying to learn how to be an "31337 h4x0r" by getting the computer to execute the machine code in the `char[]`, perhaps with the intention of using it in a buffer overflow attack. (That's what "shellcode" means in this context.) One can only hope it's for educational purposes only. ;)

Comment: Yes it is, I'm currently exploring the fundamentals of the buffer overflow attack. I intent no harm, just want to know how these things work, don't worry.

Comment: Now, **this** is interesting!